# 2 JSON. Only 1 work. json_decode php

Tags: php, json

I seriously got gray hair.

I would like to echo the [ask] data for https://api.gdax.com/products/btc-usd/ticker/

But it's return null.

When i try with to use another API with almost the same json, it work perfect.

**This example works**

```
<?php 

$url = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/ticker/btcusd";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$ask = $json["ask"];
echo $ask;
```

**This example return null**

```
<?php 

$url = "https://api.gdax.com/products/btc-usd/ticker/";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$ask = $json["ask"];
echo $ask;
```

Anybody there has an good explanation, whats wrong with the code returning null

Comment: Split it up, store the result from `file_get_contents()` in a variable first and `echo` it to see what you're actually getting back from the server. If you add that to your question, maybe we can see why `json_decode()` might have trouble with it.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the code. Server returns status code 400

Answer (score 3):

the server of that null result is preventing php agent to connect thus returning http 400 error. you need to specify a user_agent value to your http request.

e.g.

```
$ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36';
$options  = array('http' => array('user_agent' => $ua));
$context  = stream_context_create($options);

$url = "https://api.gdax.com/products/btc-usd/ticker/";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, false, $context), true);
$ask = $json["ask"];
echo $ask;
```

you can also use any user_agent string you want on the `$ua` variable, as long as you make sure that your target server allows it.

Comment: I think this is a better solution than the CURL solution. Also, I would move your comment into your actual post

Answer (score 1):

You can't access this URL without passing arguments. It happen some time when the host is checking from where the request come.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$header=array('GET products/btc-usd/ticker/ HTTP/1.1',
    'Host: api.gdax.com',
    'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
    'Connection:keep-alive',
    'Host:adfoc.us',
    'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36',
    );

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.gdax.com/products/btc-usd/ticker/");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
```

Then you can use json_decode() on $result !

Comment: Yeah I saw this, sorry for the mistake. I didn't know we could pass some options to file_get_contents !